# Loop thread hangs without `hFlush stdout` even there are no `print` things

Tags: multithreading, loops, haskell, freeze

When I test some simple cases about threaded codes,
I found some **loop  hang without `hFlush stdout`** even it does not use any `print` things.

```
import Control.Concurrent

import System.IO
import Data.IORef

delay :: Int -> IO ()
delay = threadDelay . (* 1000000)

wait sw = loop
  where
    loop = do
      v <- readIORef sw
      --hFlush stdout -- without this, hang
      if v
        then return()
        else loop

monitor sw = forkIO $ loop
  where
    loop = do
      v <- readIORef sw
      print v
      delay 1
      loop

main = do
  sw <- newIORef False
  forkIO $ do
    delay 4
    writeIORef sw True
  monitor sw
  wait sw
  --putStrLn "End"
```

This code hangs whether `monitor sw` and `putStrLn "End"` exist or not.

However, just **uncomment `hFlush stdout` in `wait`, it works properly and ends.**

This also happens with a code using `MVar`.

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.MVar
import System.IO

delay :: Int -> IO ()
delay = threadDelay . (* 1000000)

wait :: MVar Bool -> IO ()
wait sw = loop
  where loop = do
          v <- readMVar sw
          hFlush stdout -- without this, hangs
          if v
            then return ()
            else loop

main :: IO ()
main = do
  sw <- newMVar False
  forkIO $ do
    delay 4
    modifyMVar_ sw (\_ -> return True)
  wait sw
```

These two codes will run properly when running by `runghc`.

However, **the codes below are not hanging without `hFlush stdout`**.

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.MVar
import System.IO

delay :: Int -> IO ()
delay = threadDelay . (* 1000000)

wait :: MVar Bool -> IO ()
wait sw = loop
  where loop = do
          v <- readMVar sw
          if v
            then return ()
            else loop

main :: IO ()
main = do
  sw <- newEmptyMVar
  forkIO $ do
    delay 4
    putMVar sw True
  wait sw
```

---

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.STM
import Control.Concurrent.STM.TVar
import System.IO

delay :: Int -> IO ()
delay = threadDelay . (* 1000000)

wait :: TVar Bool -> IO ()
wait sw = atomically $ do
            v <- readTVar sw
            unless v retry

main :: IO ()
main = do
  sw <- newTVarIO False
  forkIO $ do
    delay 4
    atomically $ writeTVar sw True
  wait sw
```

---

I know that there are difference. But I couldn't find out **why some codes hang**.
Is `stdout` is related with handling thread?
Could you explain **why the loops are hanging or not without `hFlush stdout`**?

Additional:
1. I've tested this codes with GHC 7.10.2 {OS X, Windows}

Comment: All of these functions are inefficient busy loops, except the last STM version. Their design simply makes them hang. This is part of why STM is so nice: you get what you expect, as opposed to having to worry about temporal concerns. I would expect that `hFlush stdout` is just acting as a random delay. Tests confirm, replacing `hFlush stdout` with `randomRIO (1, 10^3) >>= delay` produces the same behaviour.

Comment: There's a `print` in `monitor`

Comment: @Joehillen Yes, there is `print` in `monitor`. However, the code hangs when comment-out or delete `monitor`. You can try that get rid any `print` things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely the compiler optimized the `wait` into non-allocating busy loop. Runtime system just doesn't have a chance to interrupt it to let the child thread to run. You can "fix" by adding any action that allocates or yields, e.g. `hFlush` or `threadDelay`. Also you can compile the code with `-fno-omit-yields`.

See also: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/367 and https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10639

Comment: The canonical "action that yields" is [`yield`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#v:yield).

Comment: Thanks, I could understand what's the problem.